picamera2 on macOS
I want to edit my Python scripts on macOS so I figured I could install picamera2 in a virtual environment to get code completion and such, but when I run pip install picamera2 I get this error:

This module only works on linux

I guess it thinks I want to use Picamera2 on macOS, when I just want the Python files for my editor's language server which I think should be fine.
Can I force pip to install it somehow?

Have you tried  this? pip install --ignore-requires-python picamera2

Tried it now and got the same error.

the post is not about the Raspberry Pi
